# Ways to compare LDA document distributions?

Tags: distance, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have an LDA model trained on a corpus of documents. The output of the model is a distribution over topics for each document; an $M\times K$ matrix, where $M$ is the number of documents in the corpus, and $K$ is the number of topics.

I am currently using the Jensen-Shannon distance to compare the similarity between distributions (compare the similarity between documents). However this requires

1. All components of every distribution to be non-zero (as we are dividing by every component in each distribution in Jensen-Shannon)
2. Storing $M\times K$ components, which is very memory expensive

Is Jenson-Shannon an appropriate metric to use here? Would any other metric be more suitable to compare documents fit to an LDA model? The Hellinger distance at least doesn't divide distribution components, so I could store the matrix as a sparse matrix which would be much more memory efficient. I would even be open to using a metric not commonly used in comparing distributions, such as a Cosine similarity, if someone could justify why it would be ok to use here.

Comment: The output of LDA is a dimensionality reduction matrix which has the linear subspace of size ($K - 1$) which maximizes the Fisher criterion subject to the assumption of equal classwise covariance matrices. Do you mean the empirical Gaussian trained with each class?

Comment: Given that you have document specific topic proportions, have you considered [Earth Mover's Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)?